# How do I define a NHibernate sql-query using mapping attributes in C#?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, sql

So for a project that we are working on we have our entire domain model mapped using mapping-attributes on the business entities themselves. I have a working sql-query mapping that I would like to define using the mapping-attributes but I am not sure how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the xml mapping that needs to be translated:

```
<sql-query name="Query1">
<return class="My.Class, My.Assembly">
    <return-property name="Field1" column="Field1"/>
    <return-property name="Field2" column="Field2"/>
    <return-property name="Field3" column="Field3"/>
    <return-property name="Field4" column="Field4"/>
    <return-property name="Field5" column="Field5"/>
    <return-property name="Field6" column="Field6"/>
    <return-property name="Field7" column="Field7"/>
    <return-property name="Field8" column="Field8"/>
    <return-property name="Field9" column="Field9" />
</return>
select Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6, Field7, Field8, Field9 from dbo.udf_CUSTOM (:Param1, :Param2, :Param3)
</sql-query>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not supported by nHibernate mapping attributes. You can define an external XML mapping if you really need to use them.

Please consider [fluent nhibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/). It's an even better way to map your objects.

Comment: We are trying to migrate a EXTEREMELY large application to fluent nhibernate. We need stake-holder buy-in. Until then, I am trying any thing I can. Can I do this with the RawXml attribute?